# Acer Aspire PC locked up and won't re-start

Tags: desktop-computer

Vista Home Premium  locked up on 5/12/10 while on a website and could not get to 'control-alt-delete.' Mouse locked, too. On/off switch would not work (stayed lit) so I unplugged the power cord. When I tried to re-start the computer I could hear a fan running but it would not boot up, nothing on the monitor and no lights on the keyboard. O/S was preloaded so I do not have a boot disk.I tried pressing F1, F2 and F11 and also with monitor off but nothing worked. Computer has not been been moved or abused so all internal connections should be fine. Have updated Windows Vista Home Premium regularly and also updated Avira anti virus and anti malware programs regularly. Using Firefox and Vista Home Premium O/S. Computer is 2 years old and was purchased new from Best Buy.

Answer (score 0):

Call (408) 533-7700 and brace for Acer "support". You're computer is likely broke, and needs repair work.

I've dealt with their "support" before and you'll likely regret buying an Acer by the time you're done. Also [this website has alternate numbers](http://www.contacthelp.com/directory/Shopping/Computers/Acer?AID=23&ListingID=228) to call.

Comment: Sounds like the laptop has gotten wet or the RAM has gone bad.